# How to disable rules for Roslyn FxCopAnalyzer?

Tags: visual-studio, fxcop, roslyn

the pre-release package of [FxCopAnalyzer for Roslyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.FxCopAnalyzers/0.7.4091001-beta) lets you disable rules in FxCop to avoid duplications, but how to disable the ones coming with FxCopAnalyzer?